# Git Log Alias not working

Tags: git, logging, alias

So I've attempted to set up an alias which will basically give me the equivalent of "git status" for any given commit.

`git log --name-status --diff-filter="ACDMRT" -1 -U HEAD`
...
it works!

So I set it up like this:

`git config --global alias.inf 'log --name-status --diff-filter="ACDMRT" -1 -U '`

And then I run it like this:

`git inf HEAD`

However, when I run the command it errors out:

`fatal: ambiguous argument '': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Anyone know why the command works directly but not as an alias?

UPDATE: I removed the -U from the end and can now execute like this:
`git inf -U HEAD`
Which works, but I don't want to type the -U... so the question remains...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by removing the trailing space a the end of your alias.

```
git config --global alias.inf 'log --name-status --diff-filter="ACDMRT" -1 -U'
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: you rock, man!  I saw your answer a while ago and it resolved the issue but apparently I hadn't flagged it, sorry!